# Update Component in react after clicking in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting to learn react so I am still grasping some concepts, now I am doing something where I need to update/render a component after one in selected in the parent one, I've read about lifting up the state, but the stuff I've done it does not work, and I have no idea what I might be doing wrong.

The first component Parent:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedDish: null, }
    this.onDishSelect = this.onDishSelect.bind(this);
  }

  onDishSelect(selectedDish) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish });
  }

  render() {
    const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
      return (
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          <Card key={dish.id}
            onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            <CardImgOverlay>
              <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {menu}
        </div>
        <DishDetail onClick={this.onDishSelect} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

and the child

```
export default class DishDetail extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedDish: null }
    this.renderDish = this.renderDish.bind(this);
  }

  renderDish(dish) {
    if (dish != null)
      return (
        <Card>
          <CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      );
    else
      return (
        <div></div>
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          {this.renderDish(this.props.selectedDish)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

When I run it I am able to see the cards of the menu, the idea is that when I click a component from the menu I can see the details in another card of the one cliked, but it is not updated, the detail component is not shown/displayed/rendered

Any Idea what I am doing wrong or missing, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`DishDetail` should accept a `prop` called `Dish` and that is it. It shouldn't have any state.

```js
    // parent render function
    const { selectedDish } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {menu}
        </div>
        {selectedDish && <DishDetail dish={selectedDish} />}
      </div>
    );


// DishDetail

class DishDetail extends Component {
    render() {
       return (
         <div className="row">
           <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
             {/* some jsx with this.props.dish */}
           </div>
         </div>
       )
    }
}
```

To keep things simple, you could even make `DishDetail` a function instead of a class:

```js
export const DishDetail = ({dish}) => (
 <div className="row">
   <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
    {/* some jsx with dish */}
   </div>
 </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wrong is where you passed onClick to DishDetail component you should pass selectedDish to DishDetail

parent component

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedDish: null, }
    this.onDishSelect = this.onDishSelect.bind(this);
  }

  onDishSelect(selectedDish) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish });
  }

  render() {
    const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
      return (
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          <Card key={dish.id}
            onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            <CardImgOverlay>
              <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {menu}
        </div>
        <DishDetail selectedDish={this.state.selectedDish} /> //add selectedDish here
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```